# Stop getting emails from firebase regarding insecure rules?

Tags: firebase

I am not providing authentication in my app. Because of this, Firebase is continuously sending me emails saying `"Firebase has insecure rules."` Can I stop these emails?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is for code specific questions and not for website or company level support. Please reach out to Firebase support directly for assistance.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please consider using [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) for questions like this that are not about code directly. Second, at the very bottom of the email, there should be an **unsubscribe** button. Also, log into your firebase console, click on the little bell icon in the top right corner. Tap the gear, and manage notifications from there.